# Layout of Android Buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I need a certain layout for an android app.  I have the custom buttons and am able to load them in to a button but need help on how to lay them out on the screen.  I am a newbie to android development (See my screen name).  Trying to learn how to use .xml

I have attached what I need and what xml code I already have.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="1">


              <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
                  <Button android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp" android:background="@drawable/schedule_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp" android:background="@drawable/grad_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
              </LinearLayout>


              <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1"
              android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
                 <Button android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp" android:background="@drawable/schedule_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
                <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp" android:background="@drawable/grad_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
              </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Her is the layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are trying to display images as buttons. Hence, I would recommend that you use ImageButton instead of a Button. I have included some code. There are a few different ways you can go about trying to achieve what you intend to here. But, I have to chosen to solely use LinearLayout just to keep it simple. Deepa has used a RelativeLayout to achieve this and it is a very good solution indeed. You should look into RelativeLayout as it might help you in the future while structuring layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

In the above code I have used the default launch icons as the images. You must replace them as necessary with you corresponding button images. Also, there are 4 important aspects here that you must understand.

First - I have used android:background="@null" to get rid of a frame that is attached to the ImageButton. Try to run the code without this line and you will understand what I am talking about

Second -  This line: android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher" is used to declare the image that you display as the image.

Third - If you want some space between the buttons you could put in some padding between each of these elements. You could do so by using the 'android:padding= xxdp'

Fourth - If you want the buttons to have a specific size, you could do so by replacing the values 'wrap_content' by 'xxdp' for the width and height. However, it is important that you add the following line when you intend to do so: android:scaleType = "fitXY". This will tell the element that you want it to be laid out in an absolute manner. But, instead of resorting to this approach, I recommend that you resize the images appropriately before getting them into your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
 <Button 
  android:id="@+id/Button1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Schedules"/>

 <Button 
  android:id="@+id/Button2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button1"
 android:text="Grand Nite"
 />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/Button3"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
 android:text="The paper"/>
<Button
 android:id="@+id/Button4"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button3"
 android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
 android:text="The Splash"
 />  

<Button
 android:id="@+id/Button5"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/Button3"
 android:text="Facebook"/>
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/Button6"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button5"
 android:layout_below="@id/Button3"
 android:text="Twitter"
 />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

It may helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

To populate this on the screen you need to set this as a view of certain activity. for that you can refer below code.

```
public class ButtonLayout extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // You can put your XML file name here
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't have problems with the java class but instead the layout in the xml file.  Any help with how to set up the xml file????

Comment: Setup the XML means..you wanted to do drag and drop like control for ease of development?